# Keeping count of button clicks in verilog

Tags: verilog, state

I am creating a vending machine in verilog. There is one button on the FPGA board to act as the coin inserter, every time the button is pushed it will add a 'quarter' to the total amount the user can spend, and display the total on the left and right seven segment displays.

Ex.
1st button push : 25 cents
2nd button push : 50 cents
3rd button push : 75 cents
4th button push : $1.00 (10 on the seven segment display).
Wont increment after the 4th button press.

```
 input quarterIn,
 output reg [4:0] state,
 output reg [4:0] next_state,
 output reg totalChange,
output reg [7:0] RSSD,
output reg [7:0] LSSD
);

 /***coin implementation***/
 parameter
    c0 = 0,
    c1 = 1,
    c2 = 2,
    c3 = 3,
    c4 = 4;
```

`always @(posedge clock)
    begin
    state = next_state;
    end`

```
 always @ (quarterIn or totalChange)
 begin
    case(totalChange)
    0: begin if(quarterIn == 1) totalChange = 1; state = c1; end
    1: begin if(quarterIn == 1) totalChange = 2; state = c2; end
    2: begin if(quarterIn == 1) totalChange = 3; state = c3; end
    3: begin if(quarterIn == 1) totalChange = 4; state = c4; end
    4: begin if(quarterIn == 1) totalChange = 4; state = c4; end
    endcase
 end
```

I am getting stuck on how to keep count of the button clicks. I can see the first value on the seven segment display, but am unsure as to how to increment the total coins. I couldn't find any sort of information on this from trying to research on my own.

Comment: States must be kept in registers. This requires flip-flops, i.e., code that typically updates on "posedge clk".

Comment: @JohanL so something like this ?                                                  'always  @(posedge clock)
 begin
 state = next_state;
 end'

Comment: Well, your stored state is essentially `totalChange`, so that is what needs to be stored.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, you need a saturating counter to keep track of the button presses.

In order to count, you need a clock in the system:

```
input clock;
```

And you'll need a reset signal to initialize the counter to a known value, zero in this case:

```
input reset;
```

And the counter (equivalent to the `state` variable, let me just call it `num_push`):

```
reg [2:0] num_push;
```

The saturating counter can be specified this way:

```
always @(posedge clock) begin
    if (reset) begin                     // Active high, synchronous reset
        num_push <= 3'b0;
    end else begin
        if (quarterIn == 1'b1 && num_push != 3'b100) begin
            num_push <= num_push + 3'b1;
        end
    end
end
```

This will synthesize to a counter with a count-enable on your FPGA and the enable will be equal to `quarterIn == 1'b1 && num_push != 3'b100`. You could press `reset` to start over.

---

Now, there are a few issues to be addressed before we put this on an FPGA. First of all, `quarterIn` needs to be synced for metastability:

```
reg quarterIn_f;
reg quarterIn_sync;

always @(posedge clock) begin
    quarterIn_f    <= quarterIn;
    quarterIn_sync <= quarterIn_f;
end
```

We should use only `quarterIn_sync` in the design and never `quarterIn` directly. You should do the same with for the `reset` signal as well.

Second, the signals that come from the keys need to be debounced. Debouncing is a whole topic in itself, so I'll skip it for the time being :(

Another thing is that the `clock` needs to be pulled from the onboard clock generator circuitry and this clock will be running at a few MHz. A typical button-press lasts for about 500ms and this means our counter will sample a few hundred thousand keypresses in a single press. To avoid this, we should count the edge of `quarterIn_sync`, and not the level:

```
wire quarterIn_edge;
req  quarterIn_sync_f;

always @(posedge clock) begin
    if (reset) begin
        quarterIn_sync_f <= 1'b0;
    end else begin
        quarterIn_sync_f <= quarterIn_sync;
    end
end

assign quarterIn_edge = quarterIn_sync & ~quarterIn_sync_f; // Detects rising edge
```

Now, replace the `quarterIn` in the saturating counter code with `quarterIn_edge`:

```
always @(posedge clock) begin
    if (reset) begin
        num_push <= 3'b0;
    end else begin
        if (quarterIn_edge == 1'b1 && num_push != 3'b100) begin
            num_push <= num_push + 3'b1;
        end
    end
end
```

And we're done!